# Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'OLD' in setup:upgrade after 2.3.2 migration

Tags: database, magento2.3, migration, setup-upgrade

Recently I migrate a site to Magento 2.3.2. **composer update** run fine and without a problem. But, when I run a **php bin/magento setup:upgrade** it throws this error:

**Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'OLD', query was: DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_text` WHERE (row_id = 472) AND (attribute_id = '44') AND (`store_id` = '0')**

The error is thrown I think when it is trying to install `Magento_CatalogStaging` module:

```
$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/var/www/gnc-2-0.morwi.mx-MIGRATION/generated/code/Composer
/var/www/gnc-2-0.morwi.mx-MIGRATION/generated/code/MSP
/var/www/gnc-2-0.morwi.mx-MIGRATION/generated/code/Magento
/var/www/gnc-2-0.morwi.mx-MIGRATION/generated/code/Symfony
The directory '/var/www/gnc-2-0.morwi.mx-MIGRATION/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
...
Data install/update:
...
Module 'Magento_GroupedProductStaging':
Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':
Module 'Magento_CatalogStaging':
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'entity_id' in 'OLD', query was: DELETE FROM `catalog_category_entity_text` WHERE (row_id = 472) AND (attribute_id = '44') AND (`store_id` = '0')
```

But I don't understand that it means. The **entity_id** column is not present anymore on **catalog_category_entity_text**, and the query the error shows is not using that column. And I don't what **OLD** means.

How can I debug and fix this error? Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you migrated an OpenSource DB in a Commerce installation

Comment: @vitoriodachef No, it was a commerce 2.0.4 to commerce 2.3.2

Comment: In 2.3.1 'OLD' is set by an event DELETE in vendor/magento/module-catalog-staging/Model/Mview/View/Attribute/Subscription.php::buildStatement l.92 and used after as $eventType in function buildEntityIdStatementByEventType l.155 to replace a parameter in a vsprintf. I never had this bug but it could be give you an idea, of where to check/put your logs.

Oh other way 2.0.4 to 2.3.2 is a big jump, you can try an update to 2.3.0 first and a second update to 2.3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I take **Vinz** suggestion about don't make the migration directly from 2.0.4 to 2.3.2, but I was more cautious and I migrate:

> 2.0.4 -> 2.0.15 -> 2.1.0 -> 2.1.10 -> 2.2.1 -> 2.2.8 -> 2.3.0 -> 2.3.2

I was solving one by one of the problems that were appearing. Maybe it was a little exaggerated, but in the end, it works.